# find a text into cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro to appear Rows depend  cell value as we  see in the code below :

```
  For a = 3 To 400
     If Cells(a, 5).value = reda Then
      Rows(a).Hidden = False
     End If
  Next a
```

and that's working well when variable = cell.value :

reda = LS700 & Cells(a, 5).value= LS700

and not working in this case :
reda = LS700 & Cells(a, 5).value = LS700/LS740.....

thank you so much advance
Reda

Comment: If I understand correctly, try `If InStr(Cells(a, 5).Value, reda) > 0 Then`. Or `If Cells(a, 5).Value Like "*" & reda & "*" Then`.

Comment: @BigBen thank you for your contribution, but unfortunately, that's not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, similar to answer by BigBen, he is missing start position on instr function, it work:

```
Dim a As Long
Dim reda As String

reda = "LS700"

 For a = 3 To 400
     If InStr(1, Sheet1.Cells(a, 1).Value, reda, 1) > 0 Then
      Rows(a).Hidden = True
     End If
  Next a
```

Comment: Start position is optional.

Comment: I try w/o start position, run time error 5 triggered "invalid procedure call". Now i got it, because I specify the compared type, therefore start position is required

Comment: that's work properly but when the variable has no value the program return a random result as hidden row randomly

Comment: Definitely you need to assign a value to the variable, if you are not going to assign a value to the variable, what is the purpose of this function?

Answer (score 0):

This is really all you should need:

```
reda = "LS700"
For Each rw In ActiveSheet.Range("E3:E400").EntireRow.Rows
    rw.Hidden = InStr(1, rw.Cells(1, 1).Value, reda, 1) > 0
Next
```